# Resize height of div so that its contents fill 100% width

Tags: css

I have a div with three images (in varying aspect ratios) in it. Lets say image1 is 16:9, image2 is 4:3, and image3 is 1:1.

I want all images to have the same height, so I set their height to 100% and their width to auto.

Now I want to scale the whole div up so that it takes 100% of the container, or in my case 100vw.

The goal is that the height of the div scales up accordingly, so that the images in the div scale up too, so that in the end I have a row of 3 images that take up 100vw and all have the same height.

The problem is that I can't get this to work. When I give the div a fixed height, the images scale up properly, but I want it the other way around, so that the height of the div is flexible and the height of the images gets scaled up until the whole row fills 100% of the container of the div.

Can someone help?`

What I have:

```
.gallerygroup3 {
    height: 500px;  /* <-- Works widht a fixed height, but not with 100% or anything else */
    width: 100vw;
}

#gallery img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `width : auto;` in `#gallery img` to `width : 33.33vw` (since there are 3 images), then try changing the div's height, and it should work. Hope this helps! :D

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but thats not what I want. The images width is nit supposed to be 33.33. they should scale up until they all have the same height, then the widht of all 3 of them together should scale up to 100vw. This means that their individual width is not 33.33, since they have different aspect ratios.